# allow quotes in textfield coldfusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm building a form through which users will be able to submit articles. my current regex allows only certain characters and works as it should, though I do not know how to allow quotes as well. here is the code

```
<cfif refind ("[^A-Z a-z 0-9\\+\-\?\!\.\,\(\)]+", trim(form.articleText)) and len (trim(form.articleText)) gte 15>
     <cfset msg = "The article can not contain special characters.">
</cfif>
```

I tried using &quot as in c# but it does not work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add quotes in your character class:

```
<cfif refind ("[^A-Za-z0-9 +?!.,()\\""'-]+", trim(form.articleText)) ...
```

Comment: This is a syntax error - quotes in CFML are escaped by doubling, not with backslashes.

Comment: Nah, you misunderstood - it needs to be `""` (though there should also be a double-backaslash to allow backslash (which the OPs version does).

Comment: (This only applies when the outer quotes are `"` - so you can have `"...""...'..."` or you can have `'...''..."...'` - hopefully that makes sense?)

Answer (score 1):

anubhava's answer gives you what you've asked for, but the solution you *probably* need is actually something completely different: to use the ESAPI encodeForX functions in CF10 to encode the *output* appropriately for its context, such as [**encodeForHtml**](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/EncodeForHTML), instead of trying to restrict what characters can be written and constantly having to update it.

At most, you might want something such as:

```
<cfif refind('[[:cntrl:]]',form.articleText) >
    <cfset msg = "The article can not contain control characters.">
</cfif>
```

Which will block unprintable control characters, whilst not preventing perfectly reasonable characters such as accented letters, currency symbols, and so on.

Comment: the reason I use the "whitelist" of characters is because certain ones should be blocked such as <> which adds additional layer of protection as it does not allow users to add something like this <script... it's not a big deal to update regex when needed :)

Comment: I know what you're trying to do, but it's the wrong approach - you should _not_ be blocking `<>` you should be **encoding** them, based on the context of where they will be used.

Comment: Correct encoding is always safe and does not place arbitrary restrictions on users. Adhoc whitelists are a big lose for usability and are only as safe as the knowledge the developers have of the syntax where the variables are being output.

Comment: here is my regex based on anubhava example [^A-Za-z0-9 +?!.,()/*:%;=\\""'-]+ I understand what you're saying for encode and will definitely try your approach as well!